# AppSync JavaScript Support for Array.sort of objects

Tags: javascript, aws-appsync, aws-appsync-resolver

While implementing JS resolvers in AWS AppSync, I can't find a way to sort an Array of objects.

The documentation of AppSync (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/built-in-objects-functions.html) mentions that Array.prototype.sort() is supported, and indeed if I pass a simple array (of Strings, for example), it is working OK. However, for objects, I can't get it to work.

Trying an inline arrow function:

```
array_of_objects.sort((a, b) => (a.event_ts - b.event_ts))
```

fails with

```
"errorType": "UNSUPPORTED_SYNTAX_TYPE",
"value": "Unsupported Syntax Type: ArrowFunction"
```

Trying an external arrow function:

```
const compareFn = (a, b) => {
        return (a.event_ts - b.event_ts)
        if ( a.event_ts < b.event_ts ){
            return -1;
          }
          if ( a.event_ts > b.event_ts ){
            return 1;
          }
          return 0;
    };

array_of_objects.sort(compareFn)
```

It doesn't sort the array in place or return a sorted array.

Trying a function argument:

```
const compareFn = function(a, b) {
        return (a.event_ts - b.event_ts)
        if ( a.event_ts < b.event_ts ){
            return -1;
          }
          if ( a.event_ts > b.event_ts ){
            return 1;
          }
          return 0;
    };

array_of_objects.sort(compareFn)
```

Fails with:

```
"errorType": "UNSUPPORTED_SYNTAX_TYPE"
"value": "Unsupported Syntax Type: FunctionExpression"
```

Comment: What about a plain function definition statement?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: `function compareFn(a, b) { ... }`

Comment: I get `Unsupported Syntax Type: FunctionExpression` error (see in the question details).

Comment: Well a function declaration statement is *not* a "function expression", so I can't say what that parser is doing. A function declaration *statement* starts with the keyword `function`, while a function expression does not.

Answer (score 2):

At time of writing this answer, the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/built-in-objects-functions.html) also states that:

> Note
>
> Array.prototype.sort() doesn't support arguments.

So you are basically stuck with the [default array sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), which sorts in place in ascending order :/

A bit disappointing isn't it?

I'm afraid your best guess would be to implement your own sorting function.

Answer (score 0):

This works at the time of writing.

Since Array.sort doesnt support anonymous functions in AppSync_JS, you need to defined your sorting function first.

```js
const sorter = (a: item, b: item ) => b.event_ts - a.event_ts

array_of_objects.sort(sorter);
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick n dirty script that can be used in aws appsync resolver. Takes care of sort, parameterised func, inline func, for & ++ constraints of appsync/js - hope it helps someone

```js
const cfunc_=(a,b)=>a>b
function bs_(arr) {
    var i=0, j,tmp1,tmp2,tmpArr=arr.slice(),sliceArr,break_=false,len = arr.length,isSwapped = false;
    tmpArr.forEach(
        (ele)=>{
            isSwapped = false;
            sliceArr=arr.slice(0,len-i-1)
            j=0;
            sliceArr.forEach(
                (tmpEle)=>{
                  if (cfunc_(arr[j],arr[j + 1])) {
                      tmp2 = arr[j]
                      arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                      arr[j + 1] = tmp2;
                      isSwapped = true;
                  }
                  j=j+1
               }
            )
            i=i+1
            if(!isSwapped)
                return
        }
    )
    console.log(arr)
}
var arr_=[2,5,2,8,4,7,2,9]
bs_(arr_)
```